# how is the ordenation for the files to cache

Tags: html, browser-cache

My problem is that I want to cache these files and all works except the images to show the icon on the buttons:

```
images/icon-18-black.png  
images/icons-18-white.png
images/icons-36-black.png
images/icons-36-white.png
```

i dont know what i doing wrong and i have control all files if they are in his corrected folder and tests in diferents orders.

someone can give me a hand?

CACHE.MANIFEST FILE:

```
index.html
boilerplate.css
master.css
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css
jquery.bxslider.css
css/shCore.css
css/shThemeDefault.css
flexslider.css
social-likes.css
images/icons-18-black.png
images/icons-18-white.png
images/icons-36-black.png
images/icons-36-white.png
images/ajax-loader.gif
imagens/Horizontal/HomeHorizontal2.jpg
imagens/Horizontal/2.jpg
imagens/Horizontal/2.2.jpg
imagens/Horizontal/3.jpg
icon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
icon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
icon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js
offlinetest.js
```

Comment: perhaps it's a path propagation issue? I'm assuming that the `images/` directory you list within your cache.manifest file is not the proper location to said file. You can check via the console and inspect the image when it's loaded into the page and look at the cache-headers.

Comment: i have solved this problem